# I don't decide yet where we visit? or I don't decide yet where we're going to visit?

Tags: tense

I don't know which one is right and normal expression.

I don't decide yet where we visit?
or
I don't decide yet where we're going to visit?

If one is the right expression, please explain the reason regarding the tense.

Comment: The correct and normal expression would be, "I **haven't decided** yet where we're going to visit." Please click on the "help v" button at the top right of the page and take the Tour. Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in this sentence, you must use the **present perfect** rather than the **present tense**.  The present perfect conveys a sense that something started in the past and is continuing until the present. The word "yet" implies that "deciding" began in the past and hasn't ended yet.  So the sentence should begin:

> I haven't decided yet where...

The second part of the sentence must use the **future tense** because the visiting has not occurred yet. Both of the following are acceptable:

> I haven't decided yet where we will visit.
>
> I haven't decided yet where we are going to visit.

The second is slightly more casual sounding.

Comment: Thank you for kind explanation. It's really helpful to me.